# Bottom margin for a page with footnotes

Tags: header-footer, footnotes, fancyhdr, geometry

I'm using geometry package in the following code. At the moment, in a page without footnotes, the margins are all 15mm, which is what I expect.

However, in a page with footnotes, e.g., Page 3, we notice that the bottom margin (that does not cover the footnotes) is larger than 15mm. Does anyone know if there is a way to make this margin exactly equal to 15mm?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[a4paper,
margin=15mm,
heightrounded,
headsep=11pt,
includehead
]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{layout}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{Author}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[C]{Title}

\begin{document}

\layout

1 \lipsum*[1]%~\footnote{abc}

2 \lipsum*[1]

3 \lipsum*[1]

4 \lipsum*[1]

5 \lipsum*[1]%~\footnote{abc}

6 \lipsum*[1]

7 \lipsum*[1]

8 \lipsum*[1]

\pagestyle{fancy}
9 \lipsum*[1]

10 \lipsum*[1]~\footnote{abc}

11 \lipsum*[1]

12 \lipsum*[1]

13 \lipsum*[1]~\footnote{abc}

14 \lipsum*[1]

15 \lipsum*[1]

16 \lipsum*[1]

17 \lipsum*[1]

18 \lipsum*[1]

19 \lipsum*[1]

20 \lipsum*[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: heightrounded is said to round the total height to a multiple of \baselineskip+\topskip. Does it help if you remove it?  There’s also an option to remove footer with nofoot.

Comment: Removing `heightrounded` doesn't help. "There’s also an option to remove footer with nofoot." ==> I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

The footnotes are smaller than normal text, so they don't constitute an integral number of the normal line height (`\baselineskip`). And there isn't enough space to fit another line of text. So there is some unused space at the bottom.

You can use the `\flushbottom` command to let LaTeX stretch the page so that it fits to the bottom, but that will make the space between the pagaraphs on that page a bit larger. Put the command somewhere before `\begin{document}`.