# Increase the bottom margin of a specific page with footers

Tags: header-footer, footnotes, fancyhdr, geometry

I'm using geometry package in the following code. At the moment, in a page without footnotes, the margins are all 15mm, which is what I expect.

However, in a page with footnotes, sometimes the bottom margin (that does not cover the footnotes) is larger than 15mm, sometimes it is smaller than 15mm. So I would like to be able to manually decrease and especially increase the bottom margin.

Does anyone know how to do that?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[a4paper,
margin=15mm,
heightrounded,
headsep=11pt,
includehead
]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{layout}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{Author}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[C]{Title}

\begin{document}

\layout

1 \lipsum*[1]%~\footnote{abc}

2 \lipsum*[1]

3 \lipsum*[1]

4 \lipsum*[1]

5 \lipsum*[1]%~\footnote{abc}

6 \lipsum*[1]

7 \lipsum*[1]

8 \lipsum*[1]

\pagestyle{fancy}
9 \lipsum*[1]

10 \lipsum*[1]~\footnote{abc}

11 \lipsum*[1]

12 \lipsum*[1]

13 \lipsum*[1]~\footnote{abc}

14 \lipsum*[1]

15 \lipsum*[1]

16 \lipsum*[1]

17 \lipsum*[1]

18 \lipsum*[1]

19 \lipsum*[1]

20 \lipsum*[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can manually decrease the bottom margin on a specific page with `\enlargethispage{5.0mm}` or similar. Negative numbers will increase the margin: `\enlargethispage{-5.0mm}`. But I'm not sure that's the best solution to your issue.

Comment: For instance, will `\enlargethispage{-5.0mm}` have an impact on the spacing (e.g., the spacing between paragraphs) in the page?

Comment: If the spacing between paragraphs is a rubber space and you have flushbottom active it might change the spacing if it needs to stretch more or less to achieve a flush bottom. Not sure how that relates to the footnotes issue though.

Comment: Is this related to your previous question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/653768/113546 ? The code looks the same. Is the solution that I gave there not adequate?